# Changing List Content with a Variable

Tags: python

Example Code

```
items = ["x", "y" "z"]
myItems = []

print(items)
get_items = input("Choose an Item: ")
myItems.append(get_items)
items.remove(get_items) 

print("Change Items Name?")
answer = input("Yes No:")
if answer == "Yes":
  print("Which Item?") 
#assuming that you can get more than one
  print(myItems)
  answer2 = input()
  if answer2 in myItems:
    newName = input("New Name: ")
    myItems[answer2] = newName
```

The Error Here is the last line.
If the user wanted to change x's name
answer2 would be x or (answer2 = "x")
but myItems[] can only accept the index of x not "x" itself. So i can't change x's name cause myItems[] can't detect it.

Of course I can Change it to

```
myItems[0] = newName #assuming x's index is 0
```

But assuming i have multiple items.
I'd have to make more lines each with a different index.

I Hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve here since i can't explain it properly myself.

Comment: You're using the wrong data structure.

Comment: I agree with @TigerhawkT3, but it highly depends on your further use of the data to suggest anything concrete. Perhaps a dictionary works better here. If needed, you can even use a list as the value for any key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last line

```
myItems[answer2] = newName
```

by this:

```
myItems[myItems.index(answer2)]=newName
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a couple of ways.

A simple method that uses a similar format to what you have is with [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> Return zero-based index in the list of the **first** item whose value is equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

Emphasis mine

An implementation using this function could be:

```
myItems[myItems.index(answer2)] = newName
```

This, however, would not work if you have multiple instances of `answer2` that you want to replace. This could be solved using [list comprehension,](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) avoiding multiple O(n) computations in favor of a single one:

```
myItems = [item if item != answer2 else newName for item in myItems]
```